# Gitlab Tee: collapsed multi-line command & unrecognized option: append

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, alpine-linux, busybox, tee

Inside of my GitLab CI file I have a file which is copied from the ["Publish npm packages instruction"](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/examples/semantic-release.html#configure-the-pipeline),

```yaml
before_script:
  - |
    {
      echo "@${CI_PROJECT_ROOT_NAMESPACE}:registry=${CI_API_V4_URL}/projects/${CI_PROJECT_ID}/packages/npm/"
      echo "${CI_API_V4_URL#https?}/projects/${CI_PROJECT_ID}/packages/npm/:_authToken=\${CI_JOB_TOKEN}"
    } | tee --append .npmrc
```

When I try to run this in Alpine Linux I'm getting.

```
$ { # collapsed multi-line command
tee: unrecognized option: append
BusyBox v1.31.1 () multi-call binary.
Usage: tee [-ai] [FILE]...
Copy stdin to each FILE, and also to stdout
    -a  Append to the given FILEs, don't overwrite
    -i  Ignore interrupt signals (SIGINT)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is simple, there are two implementations of tee,

- Busybox, which Alpine uses, has `tee` but it doesn't provide an `--append`. **It does provide an `-a` option** (short for append) which is defined as *"append to the given FILEs, do not overwrite"*
- [GNU CoreUtils provides a copy of `tee` too](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/tee) it has `--append` which you're making use of here. It's also defined as *"append to the given FILEs, do not overwrite"*. But as a shorthand, **GNU Tee also provides the alias is `-a`.**

So in short, if you want something to be compatible with Alpine and BusyBox as well as distros that ship GNU Tee then use `-a` (supported in both) instead of `--append` (supported only in GNU Tee).